# Paypal express checkout redirects to cart instead of Paypal Website

Tags: redirect, paypal-express

I have an strange issue in my magento application, When I say "**Proced Chackout**" after filling customer information, and selecting payment method as Paypal Express.

It redirects to cart, It should redirect to Paypal website.

The paypal log contains following error in responce.

```
    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-07-21T14:35:13Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 35903468d6947
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 11843215
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10412
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Duplicate invoice
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 29910
)
```

Comment: did you found any solution to this